# color rgrep matching results in the rgrep results buffer

Tags: highlighting, grep, rgrep

I am liking `rgrep` as it lets you choose a path and searches recursively. How is it possible to highlight the matches in the `rgrep` buffer?

Comment: The matches are highlighted, for me. Do you not see match highlighting if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If you see the highlighting in that case then bisect your init file to find out what is interfering.

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for the response. No they don't come out highlighted for me with emacs -Q.

Comment: OK. Might be a problem of Emacs version or a problem with your particular `find` command. Dunno. Works for me, with Emacs 23 to Emacs 26.

Answer (score 3):

`grep` (`rgrep`) uses two settings (that I know of) to control highlighting in the `*grep*` buffer

- `font-lock-mode`
- `grep-highlight-matches` - customization variable

`grep-highlight-matches` depends on `font-lock-mode` being on. It can inherit its value from `grep-host-defaults-alist`. It controls the use of the `GREP_COLORS` environment variable and `grep` `--color` argument.

In your case I'd check that `font-lock-mode` is enabled.  From the `*grep*` buffer enter: `C-h v font-lock-mode` and see what the `*Help*` buffer says. 
The easiest way to enable it in all buffers that support font locking is to call `(global-font-lock-mode t)`

You can also enter `M-x font-lock-fontify-buffer` on a per buffer basis.

I recall it not being enabled for me in older versions of emacs and/or on certain terminals.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It was actually the "match" attribute. I added this                 `(match ((t (:foreground "#f2804f" :weight bold))))
to custom-theme-set-faces and that did it.